# duply : UnsupportedBackendScheme: scheme not supported in url: sftp://user@domain.com /srv

Tags: 14.04, ssh, backup, sftp, duplicate

I'm using duply on ubuntu server and I was using *1.5.5.5-1* version of duply but getting below error suddenly.

```
UnsupportedBackendScheme: scheme not supported in url: sftp://user@domain.com /srv
Task 'BKP' failed with exit code '23'.
```

So that, I've upgrade version of duply with *1.9.1-1* but still facing same error.

```
dpkg -l | grep python-paramiko
ii  python-paramiko      1.15.1-1    all    Make ssh v2 connections with Python (Python 2)
```

Can anyone assist me with this ?

Comment: what is the url you are using_

Comment: @Jakuje target url is `sftp://user@domain.com/srv`,

Comment: There should not be the space, AFAIK

Comment: @Jakuje In my actual url there is not space, it was work before week but suddenly stop it, there is nothing change in deply.

Comment: @Jakuje Also check _ssh://_ url is also giving same error !

Answer (score 0):

I've upgrade/solve following packages :

Previously package version to upgrade:

```
duply 1.5.5.5-1 -> 1.9.1     # Still you'll get above error, So the need to upgrade "duplicity".

duplicity 0.6.18 -> 0.6.24-1
```

Then may be you'll get below error in new version:

```
 # /usr/bin/duply opt opt_backup >/var/log/duply-opt.log
 Error: BackendException: Could not initialize backend: No module named six
```

Then Do it :

```
# pip search six
six                       - Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities

# pip install six
```

If need other python module the install it like as above.